# How to loop over filenames in a directory that matches values from an array of prefixes in Python?

Tags: python

I have an array of unique values that I used to name some files. The array is:

```
import numpy as np
colors = np.array(['green','blue','red'])
```

In my directory, I have the following files that I would like to iterate over:

- green_1.txt
- green_2.txt
- blue_1.txt
- blue_2.txt
- red_1.txt
- red_2.txt

My goal is to append the contents of _1.txt and _1.txt and name the new file .txt, which I have done for 1 file below, but I'm stuck on how to incorporate the array above, into this loop below:

````
import os
# assign directory
directory = '/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/'
 
# iterate over files in that directory
for filename in os.scandir(directory):
        data = data2 = ""
        # Reading data from file1
        with open('green_1.txt') as fp:
            data = fp.read()
        # Reading data from file2
        with open('green_2.txt') as fp:
            data2 = fp.read()
        # Append file2 to end of file1
        data
        data += data2
        with open ('green.txt', 'w') as fp:
            fp.write(data)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding an inner loop over `colors` should do the trick. Also instead of assigning color names in loop, use f-strings to put in color names in iteration.

```
for filename in os.scandir(directory):
    for color in colors:
        data = data2 = ""
        # Reading data from file1
        with open(f'{color}_1.txt') as fp:
            data = fp.read()
        # Reading data from file2
        with open(f'{color}_2.txt') as fp:
            data2 = fp.read()
        # Append file2 to end of file1
        data
        data += data2
        with open (f'{color}.txt', 'w') as fp:
            fp.write(data)
```